# How to unlock a Motorola Photon 4G for other carriers?

Tags: sim-unlocking, sprint, carriers, motorola-photon

I won a Motorola Photon 4G. They are tied to Sprint, which is CDMA, but it is a world phone, which means it supports GSM and uses a SIM card. I was reading that there may be an unlock code to allow it to work with other carriers.

How can I unlock my Motorola Photon 4G for other carriers, specifically AT&T?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [AndroidCentral](http://www.androidcentral.com/ask-ac-what-happens-if-i-put-att-sim-card-motorola-photon-4g) and these [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=16680971&postcount=6) [posts](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=18233263&postcount=2), the Photon 4G is specifically made to prevent access to AT&T or T-Mobile and an unlock code won't do anything.  Presumably so that if you are in the US and don't need to roam away from Sprint, you can't switch away from Sprint.  The limitation doesn't appear to have been hacked around yet.

Comment: I was afraid that was the answer, but I wanted to check with the experts first.

Comment: -ve , bcoz I am in India and Using a Sprint Photon4g with Indian Carrier